# Display only a single CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have used the CptUI plugin to create a 'Products' CPT. The admin side of things seems to work fine but I can't quite get the front end to display how I'd like.

For example I create a product, say "Guitars" and another called "Drums". Their permalinks in admin are dispay as `http://mysite.com/products/guitars` and `http://mysite.com/products/drums` respectively which looks great. However, when I navigate to one of the URLS, I see a page that lists all the current products. This makes sense considering my `single-products.php` contains the following:

```
<?php
 /*Template Name: Products Template
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'products', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">

                <div style="float: right; margin: 10px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 100, 100 ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <strong>Name: </strong><?php the_title(); ?><br />

            </header>

            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What I'd ideally like is for `http://mysite.com/products/guitars` to display only the single CPT with the guitars content, (the same for the drums) and then `http://mysite.com/products` to display all the products (As it currently does for `http://mysite.com/products/guitars`). Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must ensure that the post type is registered with `has_archive` property set to `true`**

Look at [codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example), replace 'Books' with 'Products'

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Books', 'singular_name' => 'Book',
    'add_new' => 'Add New', 'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Book', 'new_item' => 'New Book',
    'all_items' => 'All Books', 'view_item' => 'View Book',
    'search_items' => 'Search Books', 'not_found' =>  'No books found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No books found in Trash', 'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Books'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, // <- this arg must be true
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 
  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

If you are sure 'has_archive' is true, in your theme root create a file named `products.php` that should be someting like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <div style="float: right; margin: 10px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 100, 100 ) ); ?>
                </div>
                <strong>Name: </strong><?php the_title(); ?><br />
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Than create a file named `archive-products.php` and put there simply:

```
get_template_part('products');
```

Than create a file named `single-products.php` and put there simply:

```
// yes, exactly the same thing
get_template_part('products');
```

Comment: Thanks that's great! That did exactly what I was after. It'd be helpful if the documentation made it more explicit that the `has_archive` flag was used for this.